# mysql custom order excluding Values

Tags: mysql

i think this is really simple.  I just want to return an select that has a custom order.

The result from my select is this.

Apples

Fruit

Berry

Mango

Home

Logout

I want the select to return this order

Home

Apples

Berry

Fruit

Mango

Logout

The ideal is that no matter the result `Home` is always first and `Logout` is always last.  And everything in the middle is ordered asc.  Any how would be fantastic!

Comment: I'd probably add a column, make 'Home' 1, 'Logout' 3 and the rest 2. Then I'd `ORDER BY` that column and then the column of which you posted the values (e.g. `ORDER BY ordercolumn ASC, name ASC`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'Home' THEN 1
              WHEN name = 'Logout' THEN 3
         ELSE 2
         END ASC,
         name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY  
    CASE
        WHEN ColumnValue = 'Home' THEN -1
        WHEN ColumnValue = 'Logout' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END,
    ColumnValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY IF(name = 'home', -1, (IF(name = 'logout', 1, 0))), name
```